# How to prepare PNG file for Pebble.js (CloudPebble)?

Tags: png, pebble-sdk, cloudpebble, pebble-js

Every uploaded png file to CloudPebble gives me a `Uncaught Error: Incomplete or corrupt PNG file` error during an app run-time.
I tried to save png file in different formats, compression, no compression, gray scale, indexed Pebble colors, etc.
Cannot get it working. PNG file is simple black and white icon. Followed tips in the documentation for Image Resources.
What can be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems in my case it was a CloudPebble error that has been fixed. My app compiles now no problem.

For tips on images for pebble check https://developer.getpebble.com/blog/2014/10/29/Displaying-remote-images/